# How to split string and iterate in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, explode, strsplit

I would like to know how to know how to split the string by | and - and
and display the values in php

I have string which i need to split by |and then - and display the value in php

```
<?php
$string = 'city-3|country-4';
$str1 = explode('|', $string, 2);
foreach ($str1 as $item) {
 $meal = explode('-', $string, 2);
      if (meal[0]=="city")
        {
            echo "city duration    " + meal[1]
        }
        else if (meal[0]=="country")
        {
            echo "country duration   " + meal[1]
        }
}
?>
```

```
ExpectedOutput

city duration 3
country duration 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code

1. All variables must start with a $
2. `$meal = explode('-', $string, 2);` you use $string again instead of $item
3. With PHP you've to concatenation strings with a `.` not with a `+`
4. At the end of each line you've to place a ;

If you fix al those problems you get something like:

```
<?php
$string = "city-3|country-4";
$str1 = explode('|', $string, );
foreach ($str1 as $item) {
        $meal = explode('-', $item, 2);
        if ($meal[0]=="city")
        {
            echo "city duration    " . $meal[1];
        }
        else if ($meal[0]=="country")
        {
            echo "country duration   " . $meal[1];
        }
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```